# Leer un vector o columna de un data.frame y concatenar sus elementos

Tags: r

¿Cómo podría leer un vector o columna de un data.frame y concatenar sus elementos?

```
vector <- c(uno, dos, tres)
...
```

Siendo la salida de la consola del nuevo objeto creado:

"uno, dos, tres"

Saludos,
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste(vector,  collapse = ", ")
```

`paste()` pega cadenas de caracteres. Con el argumento `collpase =`  diferente a NULL las pega a todas en un vector de largo 1.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias.